# Rearranging a sequence

Tags: python, random

I'm have trouble rearranging sequences so the amount of letters in the given original sequence are the same in the random generated sequences. For example:

If i have a string 'AAAC'
I need that string rearranged randomly so the amount of A's and C's are the same.

Answer (score 6):

```
import random
chars = list("AAAC")
random.shuffle(chars)
return ''.join(chars)
```